# Getting dropbox to sync at start-up problem

Tags: unity, sync, dropbox

Dropbox: I expect it to sync at start-up, with the dropbox icon in top bar. However, the only way I can open dropbox is by running `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` Which does work, but only while the terminal is open. Furthermore, I get this strange error, which I'm not finding in any threads :

`(dropbox:8515): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",`

I initially installed with:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

Then opened with:

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

and logged into account. When I close terminal, dropbox vanishes.
Ubuntu 14.04/Unity/64bit

Answer (score 0):

I used this https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_1.6.0_amd64.deb
Saved to my download folder
Then installed with:

```
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/dropbox_1.6.0_amd64.deb
```

Depending your l/x/k/ubuntu flavour you may have to install gdebi first:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Mine is running fine in 32bit and 64bit. Lubuntu 14.04 I just added the dropbox to my autostart to force lansync

```
dropbox lansync y
```